# epoxy paint in the basement with a wood stove?

Tags: basement

is is safe to paint my basement floor with epoxy paint with having my wood stove down there? I wanted to paint my basement floor with epoxy for the purpose of not having to repaint it each year but I have a wood burning stove down there and not sure if the heat would be bad

Comment: How do you get the old paint off the floor? Where does it tend to come off?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this a generic wood stove, or does it have a catalytic converter? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.